# Using jQuery Validation with intl phone input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using the plugin for phone number checking intlTelInput (Github) and created a custom validation method in jQuery validator as:

```
// Valid phone using the tel input check
$.validator.addMethod( "checkNumber", function( value, element, param ) {
    // TODO: Change to API check
        return (phoneInput.isValidNumber());

}, "Phone number is incorrect or invalid." );
```

This work as validation. It will default to an error when the number has the improper format but how do I use save the intl format in the form value? The puporse of the plugin is to save the format in the international format such as: +12015551256

Tutorial here:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/international-phone-number-input-html-javascript

The plugin will correctly identify a number such as (201) 555-1256 as valid and so does jQuery Validation with the above code in my validator, the issue is that after posting the form it will actually be saved as shown in the form and not the formatted intl format the plugin is supposed to use.

I think I need to pass the phoneInput to the form after validation but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I think I have to use the submitHandler and change this after submission as:

const phoneNumber = phoneInput.getNumber();

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by replacing the value with the validator SubmitHandler event:
https://api.jquery.com/submit/

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: If you have a solution, show the code you've used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).